# jQuery Datepicker dateformat

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Using the default example of Datepicker:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

How can I change the way of date is displayed to yy-mm-dd ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add dateFormat as an option -

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Taken from the API docs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Datepicker